# obfuscate multiple files using pyarmor and create single executable with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyarmor

I have some python scripts and these all scripts were imported in main.py file, so with below command tried to obfuscate and it ran successfully.

Command used to obfuscate -

At first step tried with `pyarmor gen -O -i dist3 -r scripts/` and then generated pyinstaller executable, but once after running it got some issue wrt some relative import so once checked documentation got below error,

```
from .pyarmor_runtime_000000 import __pyarmor__
```

For all the other relative import issue, please check Python documentation to learn about relative import knowledge, then check Pyarmor man page to understand how to generate runtime packages in different locations**. """

Then tried without -i - `pyarmor gen -O dist3 -r scripts/` and then generated pyinstaller executable, but once after running itbut got below error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen __main__>", line 4, in <module>
  File "<frozen scripts.xyz_tool>", line 3, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'getsha256'
```

Could anyone please help to resolve this issue ?

Thanks.

obfuscate multiple files ( which are in same folder and all files were imported in main.py file ) and create an executable but this exe should be standalone no other extra dependency libraries were required.